# dictionary to "long" dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

is it possible to take a dictionary and transform it into a "long" dataframe in polars? basically have input that looks like

```
input_ = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

and I want output like

```
┌───────┬───────┐
│ col_0 ┆ col_1 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ b     ┆ 2     │
│ c     ┆ 3     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

it possible in pandas with

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input_, orient="index").reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make *a list of the items*, then construct your [`DataFrame`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html) :

```
input_ = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} #`input` is a reserved built-in
​
df = pl.DataFrame(list(input_.items()), schema=["col_0", "col_1"])
```

Ouptut :

```
print(df)
​
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ col_0 ┆ col_1 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ b     ┆ 2     │
│ c     ┆ 3     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: thanks, actually figured out this same solution right after your reply!

Comment: Eureka effect ;) You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can just read it the normal way and then melt it.

```
pl.DataFrame(input_).melt()

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ variable ┆ value │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ a        ┆ 1     │
│ b        ┆ 2     │
│ c        ┆ 3     │
└──────────┴───────┘
```

you can feed `melt` the `variable_name` and `value_name` parameters so that you can give them more appropriate names.